# Adding a cover page to an article that uses elsarticle template

Tags: titles, elsarticle, covers

I am using Elsevier's template (`elsarticle.cls`) to write an article. I would like to add a cover page with the title, abstract and some other details, similar to the one generated by `\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle` using `IEEEtran.cls` template in peerreview mode. What is the best way to do this? I would prefer not to specify the title and abstract twice, since making modifications then becomes cumbersome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think the `elsarticle` document class has a provision for creating a titlepage of the format you're interested in.

Comment: @Mico Then could you suggest some workaround?

Comment: Can you take the relevant, i.e., titlepage-related, information from your current document and stick it into a new document that uses the `IEEEtran` document class? I'm afraid I have no better suggestion.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the suggestion. If I cannot find anything better, then of course I will do that. But the program is that this makes it harder to change the title and abstract when needed.

Comment: The thing is,  `elsartcle` is solely meant for journal submission, as is `IEEEtran`. You should get plain `article` and copy the relevant parts.

Comment: Is there any news here?